# dc.js chart_ how to make the same chart appear twice (or multiple)

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I prepare a charts with dc.js. I need to show it on two place. I try to give same id for two ***div*** but only one chart is shown. Therefore currently I have to make two separate charts with same data, same everything. the one ***div*** with different id to show the second chart which is exact look of first one.
How do I avoid repetitive codes for the second chart.
I try ***chart2 = chart1;*** but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best way is to put all your initialization in a function and then call it once with each instance. Something like:

```
function initChart(chart) {
    chart.dimension(...)
        .group(...)
        ...
    ;
}

var chart1 = dc.barChart("#id1"), chart2 = dc.barChart("#id1");
initChart(chart1);
initChart(chart2);
```

Keep in mind that if you use the same dimension they will not filter each other, so you may want to do that part separately, depending on your app.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. That's worked in a way I wanted. Same charts are shown in different views using JQuery (one on and the other off) and therefore filtering is no problem in my case.